# Adding a tool tip for for circle using python from bokeh in gmap

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

My code is

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
import bokeh.plotting as plotting
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
import tkinter as tk

screenInfo=tk.Tk()


map_options = GMapOptions(lat=26.366314, lng= 77.016513, map_type="roadmap", zoom=5)

# For GMaps to function, Google requires you obtain and enable an API key:
#
#     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
#
# Replace the value below with your personal API key:
p = gmap(API_KEY, map_options, title="Austin",plot_width=screenInfo.winfo_screenwidth()-100, plot_height=screenInfo.winfo_screenheight()-100)

source = ColumnDataSource(
    df

)

p.circle(x="lat", y="lon", size=15,name="Place", fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
plotting.output_file('gmap.html')
show(p)
```

Here I need to add a tool tip for a circle 
I tried using

```
    TOOLTIPS = [
       # ("index", "$index"),
       # ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("Place", "@Place"),
    ]
p = gmap(API_KEY, map_options, tooltip=TOOLTIPS,title="The Hindu",plot_width=screenInfo.winfo_screenwidth()-100, plot_height=screenInfo.winfo_screenheight()-150)
```

but tooltip works for only figure not for gmap.
So,is there any alternative to get tooltips.

Comment: It's really not a good idea to post your personal API key on a public forum. People can steal that key and use it for their own purposes.

Comment: Thank You Bryan.I had regenerated the key and changed the question so no Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions,HoverTool
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("Place", "@Place"),
    ("News","@Title")
]
p.add_tools( HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS))
```

I appended these Lines to  my code to get tooltip